Google Charts. Добавить линию тренда на линейный график


<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', '');
      data.addColumn('number', 'СЕНТЯБРЬ');
      data.addColumn('number', 'МАРТ');

      data.addRows([
        [1979, 10, 6],
        [1980, 20, 5],
        [1981, 10, -0.5],
        [1982, 14, 4.5],
        [1983, 15, 4],
        [1984, 6, 0],
        [1985, 5, 2.5],
        [1986, 16, 2.6],
        [1987, 14, 2.3],
        [1988, 15.5, -0.2],
        [1989, -8, -0.2],
        [1990, -5, 1.8],
        [1991, 0, 0],
        [1992, 17.5, -0.5],
        [1993, -1, 1.2],
        [1994, 11, -0.2],
        [1995, -5, -2],
        [1996, 18, 0],
        [1997, 4, 1],
        [1998, 2, 1.2],
        [1999, -4.4, -0.3],
        [2000, 2.5, -1],
        [2001, -10, -0.2],
        [2003, -5, 0],
        [2004, -6.5, -5],
        [2005, -15, -7],
        [2006, -9, -6],
        [2007, -35, -5],
        [2008, -28, -3],
        [2009, -18, -4],
        [2010, -30, -5],
        [2011, -44.5, -1],
        [2012, -18.5, -2.5],
        [2013, -19, -5],
        [2014, -29, -7],
        [2015, -29.5, -7.5],
        [2017, -25, -7.7],
        [2018, -26, -7],
        [2019, -32, -5],
        [2020, -40, -3],
        [2021, -22.5, -5]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Протяженность морского льда',
          subtitle: 'The State of the Polar Bear, Susan J. Crockford, 2021, Note 29, The Global Warming Policy Foundation'
        },
        width: 1200,
        height: 500,
        colors: ['#B22222', '#4682B4'],

        hAxis: {
          title: 'Годы (1979–2021)',
          format: ''
        },

        vAxis: {
          title: 'Разница в процентах (%)'
        },

        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {
              side: 'top'
            }
          }
        },

        //      trendlines: {
        //            0: {
        //              type: 'linear',
        //              pointSize: 5,
        //              pointsVisible: true
        //            },
        //            1: {
        //              type: 'linear',
        //              pointSize: 5,
        //              pointsVisible: true
        //            }
        //          }

      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('ice'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ice"></div>
</body>

</html>



Есть линейный график с двумя кривыми, к каждой кривой нужно добавить "линию тренда":
trendlines: { 0: {} }

Линейный график
Линии тренда
Актуально ли эта информация от Google?
Material Charts находятся в стадии бета-тестирования. Внешний вид и интерактивность во многом окончательные, но многие опции, доступные в Classic Charts, в них пока недоступны.
Вы можете найти список опций, которые еще не поддерживаются в этом выпуске.
Там присутствует trendlines.*

@像插頭一樣愚蠢, согласен. Разобрался только с Chart.js и Highcharts.js (присутствует внизу ссылка на разработчика), но надо подключать доп. плагины.  В CanvasJS есть "средняя", а тренд не нашёл, и также есть ссылка на разработчика. Платные варианты не рассматривал.

В итоге остановился на Chart.js с подключенным плагином chartjs-plugin-trendline.
